# Radio button is not getting checked in Angular (1.x)

Tags: angularjs

I am working on project with Angular JS.

I have created a group of radio button. Their values are coming from backend.

Everything is working fine.

Only problem is that Radio button are not getting checked if I try to click on them.

They are not disabled. But they remain unchecked.

Below is my HTML code for the same:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
        <label>Vehicle-3</label>
        <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
            <input type="radio" name="vc1" value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-change="updateCount()"
            ng-model="$parent.vh1" ng-disabled="dest3 === 'none'">
            {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
            <label>Vehicle-2</label>
            <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
            <input type="radio" name="vc2" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="$parent.vh2" value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-disabled="dest2 === 'none'" ng-checked="false">
            {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
            <label>Vehicle-3</label>
            <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
            <input type="radio" name="vc3" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="$parent.vh3" value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-disabled="dest3 === 'none'" ng-checked="false">
            {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
            <label>Vehicle-4</label>
            <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
            <input type="radio" name="vc4" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="$parent.vh4"  value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-disabled="dest4 === 'none'" ng-checked="false">
            {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

This is the service from where I am getting my records:

https://findfalcone.herokuapp.com/vehicles

I am adding screenshot of my application too, so that you will know what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What is vh3 here? I mean what it contains?

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya: ng-model="vh3" is the value for ng-model so that I can access the value of radio button in controller..

Comment: Anubha, see the added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to set the `ng-model` to `"$parent.vh3"` so then you can bind the value of the selected radio button outside the `radio button group`.

Make sure that name for each `input type ="radio"` button group is different.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.vehicles = [{
    name: 'A',
    total_no: 5
  }, {
    name: 'B',
    total_no: 15
  }, {
    name: 'C',
    total_no: 25
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
      <label>Vehicle-1</label>
      <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
        <input type="radio" name="vc1" value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="$parent.vh1" ng-disabled="dest3 === 'none'"> {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
      <label>Vehicle-2</label>
      <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
        <input type="radio" name="vc2" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="$parent.vh2" value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-disabled="dest2 === 'none'" ng-checked="false"> {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
      <label>Vehicle-3</label>
      <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
        <input type="radio" name="vc3" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="$parent.vh3" value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-disabled="dest3 === 'none'" ng-checked="false"> {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
      <label>Vehicle-4</label>
      <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
        <input type="radio" name="vc4" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="$parent.vh4" value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-disabled="dest4 === 'none'" ng-checked="false"> {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <pre> {{ vh1 }} {{ vh2 }} {{ vh3 }} {{ vh4 }}</pre>

</body>
```

Comment: It didnt work for me.. Actually I have four type of similar radio button. I ll update the code. Maybe thats why

Comment: Make sure that `name` of each `input type radio` button group is different, for ex : `vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4`

Comment: I can see  that `vc3` has been named twice. Also, you missed `$parent.vh3` for vehicle 3, see the update to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, that was typo here, but not in my code. Problem is this code is working fine with backend. I mean , radio button's value are updating fine in controller. Its just I checked symbol is not appearing on UI.

Comment: Hi, Your suggestion made my code work. I mean, earlier it was not even updating radio button's value in the controller. After using $parent attribute its working fine. Radio button checked was not appearing because some styles got conflicted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-repeat` is creating a child scope. So the vh3 is not directly binded to the scope of the controller. You can bind the variable to an object or use contoller as syntax which will implicitly take care of the Dot Rule.

**For more Info:** [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope) {
    $scope.modelVal = {};
    $scope.vehicles = [{
        "name": "BMW",
        "total_no": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Porsche",
        "total_no": 2
    }]
    $scope.updateCount = function() {
        console.log($scope.modelVal)
    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="ApplicationController">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
                <label>Vehicle-1</label>
                <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
                    <input type="radio" name="vc1" ng-value="vehicle.name" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="modelVal.vh1" ng-disabled="dest3 === 'none'"> {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
                <label>Vehicle-2</label>
                <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
                    <input type="radio" name="vc2" ng-value="vehicle.name" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="modelVal.vh2" ng-disabled="dest3 === 'none'"> {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
                <label>Vehicle-3</label>
                <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
                    <input type="radio" name="vc3" ng-value="vehicle.name" ng-change="updateCount()" ng-model="modelVal.vh3" ng-disabled="dest3 === 'none'"> {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `value` property and `ng-model` both contain the different value.

See, I updated the code where `ng-model` and `value` both are same. And I passed the value through `ng-change` function which you can get in the function named `updateCount`.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 radio-vehicle">
        <label>Vehicle-3</label>
        <div ng-repeat="vehicle in vehicles">
            <input type="radio" name="vc3" value="{{vehicle.name}}" ng-change="updateCount(vehicle.name, 'Vehicle-3')"
            ng-model="vehicle.name" ng-disabled="dest3 === 'none'">
            {{vehicle.name}}&nbsp;({{vehicle.total_no}})
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: But then how will I access the value of radio button in controller if it is not a variable?

Comment: Yes man, you can get. See, I passed the value through updateCount(vehicle.name). Now, this value will be available in the same function of the controller.

Comment: No I have four type of radio group. All are accessing same vehicle list. So It will difficult to analyze that from which group the value is coming. I have edited  the question and put the whole code with screenshot. So you will know.

Comment: pass the vehicle name also like ng-change="updateCount(vehicle.name, 'Vehicle-3')"